# Is every self-homeomorphism homotopic to a diffeomorphism?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Given a smooth manifold $M$, is every homeomorphism $M \to M$ homotopic to a diffeomorphism?

Hirsch's "Differential Topology" has a proof that every $C^1$ diffeomorphism of smooth manifolds is homotopic to a $C^\infty$ one, but as far as I can tell, says nothing about the case of $C^0$ automorphisms.

If false in general, is the above claim true in dimensions at most $3$? (If somehow false because of exotic smooth structures - is it true for topological manifolds supporting only one smooth structure?)

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly here. I don't understand how your parenthetical argument works, and if it works, I don't understand how it doesn't already imply what you want. Given a smooth manifold $M$ whose underlying topological manifold has more than one smooth structure, I can write down a self-homeomorphism of $M$ which exchanges two of these smooth structures. This self-homeomorphism certainly cannot itself be a diffeomorphism of $M$. (Why) does this imply that this self-homeomorphism cannot be homotopic to a diffeomorphism of $M$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I somehow convinced myself swapping the letters changed the situation. (Of course some of these various diffeomorphisms can be homotopic - there are only two homotopy classes of self-homeomorphisms of $S^7$ and 28 diffeomorphism types of $S^7$s. My aim with the letter swapping was to avoid this situation. I've edited the question to remove the parenthetical.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You say "I can write down a self-homeomorphism of $M$ which exchanges these smooth structures". In retrospect, this is not obvious to me. Why's it true?

Comment: That's the definition of what it means for the same topological manifold to support more than one smooth structure.

Comment: That theorem in Hirsch's text is much stronger than what you quote.  Hirsch proves a $C^1$ diffeo is isotopic to a $C^\infty$ diffeo, not just homotopic (a strange relation on diffeomorphisms).  Are you sure this is the question you really want to ask?

Comment: I'm aware that it's stronger, @RyanBudney. I was asking the weaker question because I didn't expect the stronger condition to be true. Based on the answers posted below it seems that (outside of $n=4$) the two questions - homotopic or isotopic - are equivalent. I haven't read the note I cite carefully, though. (I'm aware it's a somewhat unnatural question.)

Comment: @RyanBudney The theorem in Hirsch's book I found proves that the set of $C^\infty$ diffeomorphisms  between smooth manifolds $M,N$ is dense in $G^1_S(M,N)$, the space of $C^1$ diffeomorphisms between $M$ and $N$ endowed with the strong topology. Why does it then follow that any $C^1$ diffeomorphism is then isotopic to a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism? I didn't find any other theorems that seemed more relevant in Hirsch's text.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim What you need is exercises 3 and 4 in that chapter. First, because the space of smooth functions is locally path-connected, there's a small homotopy between $f$ and a nearby smooth diffeomorphism $g$. Now apply a fiberwise, relative version of the smoothing machinery to $M \times I \to M$, which in this case would say 'if $E \to X$ is a fiber bundle, and $E \to Y$ is a map, $C^1$ on fibers, then it can be approximated by a $C^1$ map, $C^1$ close to the original maps on each fiber; and if it was $C^1$ on a given closed subset, we may assume the approximation...

Comment: ...leaves the map fixed on that subset.' Then we have a $C^1$ map $M \times I \to M$, $C^1$ close on the fibers to the original $f_t$ (which, because the set of diffeomorphisms is open and we demanded the homotopy small, are all $C^1$ diffeomorphisms), leaving $f_0$ and $f_1$ fixed. That's precisely what an isotopy is.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks a lot for the help. As far as I can tell, everything seems to work if the domain and codomain weren't the same either (i.e. $f:M\to N$, $M \not = N$), right?

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim Yup, that works fine, and you could also do this sort of thing for embeddings, immersions, etc. I can't actually find this fiberwise version in Hirsch which surprises me, but I do promise it is a straightforward extension of what he does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In dimensions 2 and 3 every homeomorphism is isotopic to a diffeomorphism (this should be in Moise's book "Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3", it also follows from Kirby and Siebenmann's work). In dimension 4 there are self-homeomorphisms of simply-connected smooth compact manifolds which are not homotopic to diffeomorphisms. This follows e.g. from invariance of the $\pm$ canonical class of smooth algebraic surfaces under diffeomorphisms, while, by Freedman's work, any automorphism of the intersection form is induced by a homeomorphism.

Edit. One more useful thing: The group of homeomorphisms of a topological manifold is locally contractible (with respect to the $C^0$ topology), this is a theorem by Chernavskii (1969). Thus, if you can approximate a homeomorphism by diffeomorphisms, they will be isotopic (for sufficiently close approximation).

Comment: Thank you for the Chernavskii reference. I'd been looking for something similar but had been unable to find it.

Comment: @MikeMiller: See http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Homeomorphism_group, written by Chernavskii himself!

Answer (score 10):

In many dimensions, exotic spheres are counterexamples.

For example, the group of $7$ spheres is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{28}$.  Pick any element $\Sigma$ which doesn't *not* have order $2$, for example, a generator.

> There is an orientation reversing homeomorphism $f:\Sigma\rightarrow \Sigma$ (so $f$ has degree $-1$), but there is no such orientation reversing diffeomorphism.

Since the degree is a homotopy invariant, this provides examples of what you want.

Proof:  Since $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to $S^7$ and $S^7$ admits an orientation reversing homeomorphism, so does $\Sigma$.  Now, in the group of exotic spheres, the inverse element is the same sphere with orientation reversed.  Hence, if $\Sigma$ admits an orientation reversing diffeomorphism, then $\Sigma = -\Sigma \in \mathbb{Z}_{28}$, that is, the order of $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{28}$ is either $1$ or $2$.

$$ $$

Of course, this proof carries over to any dimension for which the group of exotic spheres contains an element *not* of order $2$.  This has to occur if the order of the group is not a power of $2$, so, according to the [chart on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere), there are examples in dimension $7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 19, 20$.  See also [the OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A001676) to find more examples.

Comment: While this answer uses exotic structures, I'm not sure I'd label your claim as "somehow false because of exotic smooth structures".  The exotic structure is just used to get a hold of the manifold to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

First, note that a homeomorphism $f$ of compact smooth manifolds is homotopic to a diffeomorphism if and only if one can approximate $f$ arbitrarily well by diffeomorphisms.

For $n \leq 3$, [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183523321) of Munkres claims as a corollary that a homeomorphism $f: M \to N$ of smooth manifolds may be approximated arbitrarily well by a diffeomorphism. This settles my question here. There is a  harder question of whether or not every homeomorphism is isotopic to a diffeomorphism. The consensus on [this MathOverflow question and answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/82126/40804) seem to be that it's true for $n=2$, though I haven't checked the stated references. Ian Agol's answer there sounds like it's true for $n=3$, but I'm not sure.

[This note](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1002) of Stefan Müller gives a proof that for $n \geq 5$, a homeomorphism of compact $n$-manifolds can be approximated arbitrarily well by diffeomorphisms *if and only if* the same homeomorphism is isotopic to a diffeomorphism.

Every related question in $n=4$ seems to be wide open.

Comment: "First, note that a homeomorphism $f$ of compact smooth manifolds is homotopic to a diffeomorphism if and only if one can approximate $f$ arbitrarily well by diffeomorphisms."

I might be missing something obvious. Why is this true?

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim The space of homeomorphisms is locally path-connected, as in studiosus's answer.